# How many ways can I partition a string of length n into k parts? k can be >n.

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can I partition a string of length n into k substrings? k can be >n, and hence some parts can be empty also. For example, if the string is 'abc' and k = 4, then the possible partitions are (, seperates the parts)

```
abc,,,,
ab,c,,,
ab,,c,,
ab,,,c,
a,bc,,,
a,b,c,,
a,b,,c,
a,,bc,,
a,,b,c,
a,,,bc,
,abc,,,
,ab,c,,
,ab,,c,
,a,bc,,
,a,b,c,
,a,,bc,
,,abc,,
,,ab,c,
,,a,bc,
,,,abc,
```

Comment: So this is the number of ways of getting $k$ nonnegative integers to add up to $n$, a question which has been asked and answered on this site many many many times. Please, have a look for earlier occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you want to get an ordered list of substrings with empty ones. If the length of your string is $m$, you have to place $n-1$ delimiters in
$m+n-1$ possible positions. So the answer is
$$
C_{m+n-1}^{n-1} = \bigl(\substack{m+n-1\\ n-1}\bigr) = \frac{(m+n-1)!}{(n-1)!\,m!}
$$
In your example $m=3, n=4$ it is $$ C_6^3 = \bigl(\substack{6\\3}\bigr) = 20 $$